# Fabricjs Setting button to toggle lock on movement x axis

Tags: fabricjs

I'm making a image manipulation tool in a fabricjs canvas,I need to add some position fixed rectangles with movement in the Y axis but at the same time allow the user to move them in the x axis if necessary,

The mentioned rectangles are fixed with the following property when summoned as:

```js
// creates a rectangle object for text1
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    fill: 'rgba(0, 16, 8, 0.45)',
    left: 150,
    top: 200,
    width: 700,
    height: 120,
    centeredScaling: true,
    lockMovementX: true,
    stroke: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10)',
    strokeWidth: 0.1,
});

// adds rectangle onto canvas
canvas.add(rect);
```

This can acomplish by adding a checkbox and toggle between true and false states, like in this demo:

http://fabricjs.com/controls-customization

with the following variable as in the fabric js documentation:

LockMovementX :Boolean
When `true`, object horizontal movement is locked

these references are also useful for this objetive:

http://fabricjs.com/customization

https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/wiki/Preventing-object-modification-(movement)

http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#lockMovementX

but so far i haven't been able to get a functioning toggle button for this variable, can someone help me get this figured out?

here is a js.fiddle with an example of my code: https://jsfiddle.net/Cuernacow/d1jve8w9/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how to setup this properly:

In the HTML code:

```
<p>hasControls</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="hasControls" checked="">
<p>Visible</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="visible" checked="">
<p>Lock x axis</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="lockMovementX" checked="">
<p>Lock y axis</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="lockMovementY" checked="">
```

In the fabric js code:

```
//-------- Observe checkbox boolean value
//Each Id property in the html is used as an boolean property by fabric js 
//getActiveObject() selects the current active object in the canvas to apply such  property

function observeBoolean(property) {
document.getElementById(property).onclick = function() {
  canvas.getActiveObject()[property] = this.checked;
  canvas.renderAll();
};
  }

  //-------- Declaration of boolean variables to observe

  observeBoolean('hasControls');
  observeBoolean('visible');
  observeBoolean('lockMovementX');
  observeBoolean('lockMovementY');
```

And the updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Cuernacow/d1jve8w9/18/

Comment: Could you modify your fiddle to lock X or Y movement when ALT key is pressed?

Comment: Here, updated it to toggle a click event for both X and Y when ALT is pressed

https://jsfiddle.net/Cuernacow/d1jve8w9/83/

Comment: I Added a function an named the checkboxes to be called by the function:

`document.onkeydown = function(e) {
 if (18 === e.keyCode) {
  // 18 is Alt key
  $('input[name=LockMovementX]').trigger('click'); // Triggers a click on LockMovementX
  
  $('input[name=LockMovementY]').trigger('click'); // Triggers a click on LockMovementY 
  
}}`

You can change the button by replacing the key code for the ones mentioned in this website:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/